# translate custom message in other language in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, checkout

I am customizing woocommerce, adding custom fields in woocommerce checkout form and custom messages via hooks in functions.php

The site which I am customizing is in two languages French and English, default is French.

How to display strings, which I am adding like labels of woocommerce checkout field in those languages, when French is selected, strings should be in French and when English is selected, strings should be in English.

Comment: To make `$string = "This is my string";` translatable, you need [**to use the `__()` function**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) this way: `$string = __("This is my string");`

Comment: After that? Where to put translations??